# Filter a string in PHP

Tags: php, stripos

I'm looking to get an array of ID's from the following string.

`[vc_gallery type="flexslider_fade" interval="3" images="3057,2141,234" onclick="link_image" custom_links_target="_self" img_size="large"]`

Ideally, i'd like to look at this string and get an array of the INT values within images. e.g.

`array("3057", "2141", "234");`

Comment: is the number of values (inside images) varying?

Comment: Yes, it could not be present, or there could be any amount, comma delimited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find images value and explode it to receive array

```
$str = '[vc_gallery type="flexslider_fade" interval="3" images="3057,2141,234" onclick="link_image" custom_links_target="_self" img_size="large"]';

if (preg_match('/images\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/', $str, $m)) {
   $res = explode(',', $m[1]);
   print_r($res);
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit over doing this VS stripos?

Comment: there are many variants. You can use stripos. Can use explode some times

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `explode` and `strpos` functions:

```
$str = '[vc_gallery type="flexslider_fade" interval="3" images="3057,2141,234" onclick="link_image" custom_links_target="_self" img_size="large"]';

foreach (explode(" ", $str) as $v) {
    if (strpos($v, "images=") === 0) {
        $result = explode(",", explode('"', $v)[1]);
        break;   // avoids redundant iterations
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3057
    [1] => 2141
    [2] => 234
)
```